# Android call public method on Fragment added in XML

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-xml

I have a Custom Fragment that I have created which is added into my main activity XML layout like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Hello world"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<fragment android:name="net.project.package.fragments.CustomFragment"
    android:id="@+id/custom_fragment"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

The custom fragment contain a public method like below:

```
public void myPublicMethod() {

    //do some stuff

}
```

however in my Activity I am not able to access this public method when I call the view:

```
Fragment myCustomFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.custom_fragment);

myCustomFragment.?
```

What is the way to call this method when a fragment is declared in XML?

Comment: You need convert to CustomFragment 
`CustomFragment myCustomFragment = (CustomFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.custom_fragment);
myCustomFragment.myPublicMethod();`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to typecast the fragment to your Fragment containing the method that you retrieve from the fragment manager. Also, you should check if the fragment is null or not before actually calling any method in the fragment.

CustomFragment myCustomFragment = (CustomFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.custom_fra‌​gment);